# joining tables in mySQL to get a particular column

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables :

```
- cart , cols are (painting_id, session_id, ip, user_agent)
- paintings , cols (painting_id, price)
```

Now I have to select the painting id from the table cart. I need to Join the two tables and get the sum of the price of all the paintings from table 'paintings'. Note the table cart doesnt have the price column , it has to be imported from the 'paintings' table. Only the sum of price of those paintings are shown which has been added into the cart table by a particular session id or email id.

Here is the query i have tried so far

```
SELECT p.SUM(price) FROM paintings 
p JOIN cart c ON p.painting_id = c.painting_id 
WHERE c.session_id = '$session'
```

Comment: you need to use group by

Answer (score 1):

It should be `SUM(p.price)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT cart.user_agent, sum(paintings.price)
from cart inner join
paintings on 
cart.painting_id=paintings.painting_id 
where session_id='$session'
```

if you want the total cost of all the users

```
SELECT cart.user_agent, sum(paintings.price)
from cart inner join
paintings on 
cart.painting_id=paintings.painting_id 
group by cart.session_id
```